# How to import the exported yaml of a view

Tags: views, configuration, 8

When attempting to import a view's exported yaml, the following message is received:

```
The configuration cannot be imported because it failed validation for the following reasons:
Configuration menu_export.export_data depends on the menu_export extension that will not be installed after import.
Configuration menu_export.settings depends on the menu_export extension that will not be installed after import.
```

There is no such dependency in the yaml, and there is no D8 menu_export module.

Comment: How did you name the view's exported yaml file? Based on the error message, it's not clear that the problem is related to the exported yaml of  view. I think the exported view yaml file needs to be something like views.view.your_view_name.yml

Comment: I think that you must be referring to a different context. This is a single item (view) import through the UI, which has you paste the yaml contents in a window.

The error message is generated in core in the function that checks for dependency errors.

Comment: Oh, sorry for the misunderstanding! And I'm sorry I don't have any experience with importing through the UI, so I can't offer any assistance. Hopefully, someone else will chime in.